# Private functions can be called publicly if the object is instantiated within the same class

Tags: php, oop

```
<?php
 //5.2.6
class Sample {
    private function PrivateBar() {
      echo 'private called<br />';
    }

    public static function StaticFoo() {
      echo 'static called<br />';
      $y = new Sample();
      $y->PrivateBar();
    }
 }

 Sample::StaticFoo();
?>
```

The above code will output:

```
"static called
 private called"
```

Why does $y->PrivateBar(); not throw an error?  It is a private function after all.

What is the object oriented design logic behind this?  Is this unique to PHP, or is this standard OOP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because StaticFoo, though static, is still considered part of the Sample class.

This is also reproducable in C#:

```
public class Sample
{
    private void PrivateBar()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("private called\r\n");
    }

    public static void StaticFoo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("static called\r\n");
        Sample y = new Sample();
        y.PrivateBar();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Sample.StaticFoo();
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

With the output:

```
static called

private called
```

Answer (score 1):

> Why does $y->PrivateBar(); not throw
>   an error? It is a private function
>   after all.

Private function do not throw an error when you use them inside the class, they throw the error when accessed out side of the class.

> What is the object oriented design
>   logic behind this? Is this unique to
>   PHP, or is this standard OOP?

It is not unique to PHP and is standard OOP.

Comment: $this is null in a static function.

Answer (score 0):

> Actually you are calling the private method with in the class, So that it does not throw error.
>
> If you do the same thing out of the class , It will throw the error.